# Xcode 9 - Could not load the “sampleImage” image referenced from a nib

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I converted Swift 3.1 to Swift 4.0 syntax using Xcode 9.0 beta, and I have a strange problem. My images in Assets folder in the project are not loaded on my real device. I receive this information `Could not load the “sampleImage” image referenced from a nib`. Everything works fine in simulator. Can somebody explain me, why?

> Update

After updating my iOS to `iOS 11` I can see images in my app. But does it mean, that apps installed on iOS 10 and earlier will have a problem with displaying images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt apps running iOS 10 and earlier will have problems displaying images. In my experience as an iOS developer when you update to a beta Xcode release and Swift SDK you have to update to the newest iOS beta to utilize the SDK and test apps. That changes once the beta tags are removed.

The following Apple document states that *"The beta OS must be installed on your device (Mac, Apple TV, Apple Watch or iOS device). The beta OS, when offered, is available on the respective developer download page. For example, see iOS Downloads."*

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2249/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

> I post an answer to another question about that. Please check this for more detail:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/44683381/3797903

Just convert all your jpg asset to png to make it run on iOS 10 or earlier device.