# Xcode 9, iOS 10 issue with Assets

Tags: ios10, assets, ios11, xcode9-beta, xcode9

I'm having a problem with assets and Xcode 9 beta running on devices with iOS 10. It doesn't upload any image from assets, so on the phone I can't see any asset!

If I load images in the storyboard, it just doesn't show any image on the phone (but it shows in the storyboard), if I do something:

`UIImage(named:"imageName")!`

It crashes with log message:

> *** Assertion failure in -[_CUIThemePixelRendition _initWithCSIHeader:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-428.6/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m:3788
>   Could not load the "imageName" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "myIdentifierName"

This is strange as the same code running on another device with iOS 11 beta works and I can see the images.

Comment: This is maybe a bug I guess. Try using `Image Literal`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but no, even with `Image Literal`it crashes. I guess it's a bug, but quite big as I can't use any assets!

Comment: Take a look at [Xcode 9 Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_2/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_9_beta_2.pdf) on __Asset Catalog__ section.

Comment: I have this bug even with png assets and iOS 11...

Comment: I am using Xcode 10 Beta, if I run the app on the iOS 12 simulator all is fine, but if I use a device with iOS 11.4 the images doesn't show

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got same problem when I test app on iOS 10.
Check the Xcode 9 beta release note and found known issues about that:

> Asset Catalog
>
> - Jpeg assets in asset catalogs are not found on iOS 10 or earlier for apps built with Xcode 9. API calls for accessing the image such as UIImage.imageNamed: return nil. (32524123)
>     **Workaround**: Use png resources or limit app testing to devices running iOS 11 or later.

After convert all my jpg asset to png. It's works well. Oh...

Answer (score 4):

I got same issue even in xcode 9 beta 4. 
Solved by just checking this for Image.

[image]

Hope It helps.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in Xcode 9 beta 3 (build 9M174d)

> Jpeg assets in asset catalogs are found on iOS 10 or earlier for apps built with Xcode 9. (32524123)

Answer (score 0):

Make build with ios 11 device or generic ios device